# Get all items of a Sharepoint document library using Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve a document library by path using the Graph API and I'm not sure how to proceed.

The url to the library is for example the following:

```
https://hostname/sites/sitename/subsite/nameofdocumentlibrary/
```

I would like to have all the children through the Graph API. The issue: I know the document of the library but I don't know the ID of the library. It seems that it's possible to access it through the relative path but I'm not succeeding to it.
How do I do this?

My get url was the following:

```
/v1.0/sites/hostname:/sites/sitename/subsite/nameofdoccumentlibary/items
```

I'm always getting:

> The provided path does not exist, or does not represent a site or UnknownError.

Any ideas ?

Comment: If I do : /v.10/sites/subsiteID/drives/ , I get UnknownError ... :s

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{hostname},{spsite-id},{spweb-id}/lists/{list-id}
```

I don't check this in real life because I don't have SP Online. But it must working.
Use [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0) with SharePoint Graph API.

To get site id (site collection) you can go to your site collection and browse this endpoint:

```
https://hostname/sites/sitename/_api/site?$select=Id
```

To get web id (subsite) you can go to your subsite and browse this endpoint:

```
https://hostname/sites/sitename/subsite/_api/web?$select=Id
```

To get library Id you can just open Document Library Settings page. URL have library ID. You can transform it to real guid. Like this:

```
/_layouts/15/listedit.aspx?List=%7B603D7FA3-C801-46EB-A044-421234452901%7D
```

Must transformed to:

```
603D7FA3-C801-46EB-A044-421234452901
```

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed working ;) I can retrieve the document library through: /sites/subsiteid/lists/libraryid. But what I actually want to achieve is retrieve this same document library through it's relative path. Is this possible? I see the url of the library : https://hostname/sites/sitename/subsitename/nameofdocumentlibrary/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Comment: I see here (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-sharepoint-list-using-microsoft-graph-explorer-in-office-365/) that list object has webUrl property. May be you can use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{hostname},{spsite-id},{spweb-id}/lists endpoint to get your list by this property. If Graph API not have filter operator in this endpoint then you can get all lists and filter on client side. Exact answer I don't know. Only suggestions. =)

Comment: I cannot to call this endpoint by myself. Because that I think that /lists endpoint will return webUrl property. If not then I don't know how to do that. In SharePoint out-of-box REST API no exists methods to get list by url officially documented.

Comment: Here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-get?view=graph-rest-1.0 I saw response. List object has 'name' property. You can try to filter list by its name not by url. In SharePoint out-of-box REST API it is common practice to use list name to get it. Like this: /_api/web/lists/getByTitle('<LIST_NAME>')

Answer (score 0):

Following your feedback, I could now retrieve the document library using the display name (not the path in the url).
This is my request:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/fullsubsiteid/lists/69369/items
69369 is my display Name here.
I can also use:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/fullsubsiteid/lists/69369/drive

Now the first request, is returning an empty value array, while there is a "Documents" folder in the document library. How could I retrieve all folders/files etc in this document library? How can I use relative path?

Tx!

Comment: I've found how to list the files in a library & folders: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/fullsubsiteid/lists/69369/drive/root:/Documents:/children

Comment: MS documentation is not clear about this ... I still don't know how I could use the web url of the SP document library to access the library ..